# Required variables at queue time

Tags: azure-devops

When running our Release build (which ultimately labels and versions a changeset), I want the variables to be supplied at queueing time.  For example `1.0.23` below:

[image: Queue Build]

Is there any way to set these variables as required in order to execute the build?

[image: Build variables]

This new "vNext" build platform is incredibly difficult to Google for.

Comment: Not quite clear what you're asking about. How do you expect it to work? Are you looking for the way to automatically pull the values from somewhere and preset the variables at build time?

Comment: @YanSklyarenko I read it as someone must either save them in the definition or supply them at queue time. It was a concept in the XAML builds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best I have come up with thus far is to add a task as the first step in the first phase of the build that checks the required variables are set. If any are not, it fails the build.

I use PowerShell for this:

```
if ([string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($env:Major)) { throw "Major not set" }
```

This is not ideal, as the build still has to wait to get scheduled on an agent, sync sources, &c. before the validation code runs and fails the build. But, it's still better than building everything just to have, say, packaging (step 14/15) fail because the version wasn't set.

I've opened a [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365977/required-variables-in-build-definitions.html) on the VSTS UserVoice page asking for "required queue variables".

Comment: Your link is dead. I'd like to support that feature request.